# Starting with Python 3 and Avro 1.7.6, what are the steps? (Q&A)

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, schema, avro

This is a Q&A, meaning I am sharing my solution/answer to a problem I faced:

The problem was that the [getting started guide](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html) from the apache site was not entirely up- -to-date and after a bit of fiddling I manage to get the sample to work.

1. First wget the latest release from [here](https://github.com/apache/avro/releases)
2. Go to the py3 subfolder under lang and build the project via your python 3 (read more [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html))
3. Create user.avsc in the same folder as the python code is going to be located.

   The schema:

   ```
    {

     "namespace": "example.avro",
     "type": "record",
     "name": "User",
     "fields": [
         {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
         {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
         {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
     ]
    }
   ```
4. Create the .py from the code provided below (Mind that I had to make minor changes to the code in [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html) to get this to work).

   The modified code is as follows.

   ```
   import avro.schema
   from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
   from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

   schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("user.avsc").read())

   writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
   writer.append({"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256})
   writer.append({"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "red"})
   writer.close()

   reader = DataFileReader(open("users.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
   for user in reader:
       print(user)

   reader.close()
   ```

Comment: Code example has typo. Should be import avro.schema not import import avro.schma

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. First wget the latest release from [here](https://github.com/apache/avro/releases)
2. Go to the py3 subfolder under lang and build the project via your python 3 (read more [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html))
3. Create user.avsc in the same folder as the python code is going to be located.

   The schema:

   ```
    {

     "namespace": "example.avro",
     "type": "record",
     "name": "User",
     "fields": [
         {"name": "name", "type": "string"},
         {"name": "favorite_number",  "type": ["int", "null"]},
         {"name": "favorite_color", "type": ["string", "null"]}
     ]
    }
   ```
4. Create the .py from the code provided below (Mind that I had to make minor changes to the code in [here](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedpython.html) to get this to work).

   The modified code is as follows.

   ```
   import avro.schema
   from avro.datafile import DataFileReader, DataFileWriter
   from avro.io import DatumReader, DatumWriter

   schema = avro.schema.Parse(open("user.avsc").read())

   writer = DataFileWriter(open("users.avro", "wb"), DatumWriter(), schema)
   writer.append({"name": "Alyssa", "favorite_number": 256})
   writer.append({"name": "Ben", "favorite_number": 7, "favorite_color": "red"})
   writer.close()

   reader = DataFileReader(open("users.avro", "rb"), DatumReader())
   for user in reader:
       print(user)

   reader.close()
   ```

Comment: you missed "e" in avro.schema.

Comment: Thanks for that fixed. :)

Comment: I guess it  should be 'avro.schema.parse' instead of 'avro.schema.Parse'. "p" of parse in lowercase

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new project and then set python 2.7 as system interpreter and then import avro.

i got the output as in documentation https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.8.2/gettingstartedpython.html

```
{u'favorite_color': None, u'favorite_number': 256, u'name': u'Alyssa'}
{u'favorite_color': u'red', u'favorite_number': 7, u'name': u'Ben'}
```